# $PSL(n,q)$ is simple: Proof

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

That group $PSL(n,q)=SL(n,q)/(center)$ is simple is proved on the following lines:

(1) $SL(n,q)$ acts on (non-zero elements of) $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

(2) Action of $SL(n,q)$ is doubly transitive, hence for any $v\neq 0$, the $Stab(v)$ is maximal.

(3) $Stab(v)$  contains an abelian normal subgroup $K$, s.t. conjugates of $K$ generate $SL(n,q)$.

(4) Thus $SL(n,q)$ modulo kernel of action (which becomes equal to center) is simple.

This proof can be found in Suzuki's or Alperin-Bells book on Group Theory.

However, the arguments follow a very general theorem, known as [Iwasawa theorem (1941)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4x8BCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&dq=Iwasawa%20theorem%20simple%20group&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6wEwADgKahUKEwj77cPssZnJAhXCGJQKHcndB0k#v=onepage&q=Iwasawa%20theorem%20simple%20group&f=false). But the simplicity of $PSL(n,q)$ is know much before this theorem proved.

**Question:** How it was proved, before Iwasawa's theorem, that $PSL(n,q)$ is simple? [one may just outline the proof, and/or suggest references for it.]

---

Note: $PSL(n,q)$ is simple except $(n,q)=(2,2), (2,3)$. We do not consider it above.

Comment: Presumably the old algebraists just proved with their bare hands that the normal closure of any nontrivial element is the whole group.

Comment: In (2), the doubly transitive action is on the $1$-dimensional subspaces of the vector space, not on its non-zero vectors. As to your question, I think you have it the wrong way round. Iwasawa looked at the original proof and extracted part of it as a separate theorem which could be used in the simplicity proofs of the other classical groups.

Comment: is it almost the same way to prove the simplicity of PSU(n,q) ?